# is there an jackon jar file in the spring 4 release

Tags: spring, rest

I am new to spring with rest api and I want to know is there jackson jar in the spring 4 or spring 4+ release because I am getting the no class found exception for jsonGenerator

Comment: Please add more details e.g. how you are getting the spring dependencies, your dependency tree from whatever build tool you are using.

Comment: I think jackson-core  dependency is missing in your pom.xml

Comment: When you say Spring 4 or 4+, I am assuming you are talking about core Spring. For Spring Core and Spring MVC (spring-webmvc), you need to add jackson-core dependency in your pom. But if you use Spring Boot, "web" dependency should do the magic for you.

Comment: Hi, I am just created the dynamic web project and added the spring-4.1.4.RELEASE jar, done configuration  for rest api servlet .xml at On server start up I am getting classnotfpund exception for com-fasterxml-jackson-core-jsongenerator

Comment: Solved, Added jar files related to jackson such as com.fasterxml.jackson.core, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind, jackson-annotations-2.5.0